# How to ensure that my website is reasonably secure from being hacked?

Tags: xml, security, web

I have a website for my family business. I just have a few pages and some product catalogue. There wont be any online transactions or payments. Just some html pages, javascript files and a product catalogue stored in xml files.

I would like to know how can i ensure that my website is reasonably secure from being hacked? What can i do, to at least implement some level of security, for instance, what can i do to make sure my xml file is not altered or accessed by someone?

Comment: is the site live? why don't you post it here so that we can mention the security loopholes?

Comment: Currenly, no. its still under development but at the point of completing soon, but just before i put it up online, i thought it would be be good to find out more abt security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read up on xml security [HERE](http://home.comcast.net/~fjhirsch/xml/xmlsec/starting-xml-security.html).

Digital Signatures, good passwords, Security Certificates and Firewalls are good ways to ensure a secure Web Server.

Answer (score 5):

At a minimum, read up on the OWASP Top 10.  Even if you're not serving up insecure content, you still want to protect against Cross-Site Scripting, SQL Injection, etc.

The OWASP site is an almost un-beatable resource for secure website development.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using PHP or other dynamic languages, you're basically as secure as you'll ever be.

Just a few more tips:

- **Turn off SSH and FTP**. If there is no way to get into your server, nobody is getting in.
- **Keep your server up-to-date**. Software is exploited, but if you are using decent server software (e.g. Nginx, Lighttpd, Apache), a bugfix release will be released quite quickly.

Comment: Hi, I assume, the server administration and maintenance is taken care of by the web hosting company. Am i right to say that? And if so, the two tips you gave me is something they (web hosting company) should take care right?

Comment: How are you supposed to upload your website's files if the FTP server is turned off? I was thinking that you were hosting the site. As you aren't, my comments don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

This information varies based on your web sever, for example if you want Apache to refuse to serve a file to someone who is not in a known list of hosts, or who does not authenticate you can configure some fancy stuff in .htaccess.  I'm afraid you'll have to look up some documentation to know the specifics of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad topic. The essential of security is to prevent unauthorized users accessing/modifying/deleting your data.

general speaking, the key problem is:

1. how to detect and log the behaviors are unauthorized or not.
2. how to stop the unauthorized behaviors, or reduce the impact of being attacked.
3. how to deal the issue if you site has already be hacked.

According to your description, if you wanna protect you site, try the following approaches:

1. use strong password in both you host accounts and web system accounts.
2. start up a firewall and set proper rules, such as filter ports which needn't open to the public.
3. use HTTPS connection to protect you visitors from the HTTP hijacking.

in additions, all the things that to make your data safer will cost more resource like CPU time, memory, response time, disk space or money.